# Eliminate rows in a dataframe after looping through all rows of column and applying condition

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data frame with 5 rows and 3 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,4,4,3,7], 'B': [1,2,2,6,4], 'C': [1,2,2,6,4]})
```

I have to find a way to drop a row if the datapoint in column A is finding a value higher than itself in column A, and the B value of that row is lower than the B value of the querying row.

For example, in the above data frame row 4 has to be dropped because it has higher values in column A (4, 7) with less B value (2,4).

I will modify the question in a application perspective for better clarity. Sorry for my bad presentation skills.

Lets say this is our dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'resources': [100,200,300,300,400,400,400,500,1000],
                   'score': [1,2,1,2,3,5,6,8,9]})
```

I want to find a trade-off with resources i use and my score. My priority is to get the best score with less resources. I iterate all combinations and see if a row is eligible to be considered. So basically in this 9 rows, rows 3, 4, 5,6 should be eliminated 3 because 1 gives the same score with less resource, 4 because 2 gives the same score with less resource, 5 and 6 because 7 gives a better score with same resource. I hope this will make my problem more clear.

Comment: can you show an example of the desired output if possible ?

Comment: All rows except row 4

Comment: So the sorting order matters? what if you moved index 3 in second position? How far away do you want to search in case of fluctuating values? For clarity, when you say "row 4" you mean index 4 or position 4 (i.e. index 3)?

Comment: If we draw a table this will have 3 columns and 5 rows. Here, 4th row should be dropped. Sorting order does not matter but every row has to check itself with all other rows to satisfy the condition.

Comment: it's still unclear if you want to filter on the resources or score? you seem to want to "optimize" both at the same time, which seems tricky. Can you provide the output you expect for your second example in the same format as the input, because it looks like you're counting the rows from 1 while python used 0 so your textual description is highly ambiguous?

Comment: I want to filter both resources and score. I want the best combinations only. The output will be df=pd.DataFrame({'resources'[100,200,400,500,1000], 'score': [1,2,6,8,9]})

Comment: OK, I provided a solution to my understanding of the problem, I hope this is what you want

Comment: Have you had a chance to give it a try?

Comment: df7 = pd.DataFrame({'resources': [18133,18399,18649,18999],
                   'score': [400,100,300,200]}) The answer could not solve this example....all points except first row has to be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   1
1   4   2   2
2   4   2   2
3   3   6   6
4   7   4   4
```

You can do:

```
mask_a = df.A.apply(lambda x: (df.A > x).any())
mask_b = df.B.apply(lambda x: (df.B <= x).all())

df[~(mask_a & mask_b)]

# Output
    A   B   C
0   1   1   1
1   4   2   2
2   4   2   2
4   7   4   4
```

Comment: No, i dont want to compare A and B directly.  I don't know how to implement this logic in python. I start with the first row and check all other rows if there is a higher A value "AND" lower B value, if this is not satisfied I dont drop that row. Here, for the first row there are higher A value but no value is lower than the 1 in B so it should not be dropped. Likewise, iterate all rows.

When doing like this row 4 is dropped because it can see there are higher values than 3 in A and lower values than 6 in B .

Comment: I edited my answer. If I understand correctly, what you want is to check every row and drop those where there is a **higher** value in `A` **AND** where there is a **lower** value in column `B`. If that's correct than the only rows that will be left are the first and last one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are so near to understand me and sorry for my english.  A small mistake, you should not eliminate rows 1 and 2 because 2 (value in B of row 1 and 2 ) is less than 4(value in B of row 4)

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not what i wanted, please see my edited question with a application perspective. Again sorry for my bad clarity in explaination

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find a trade-off with resources i use and my score. My priority is to get the best score with less resources

Ok, then I'd do this:

```
df["ratio"] = df.score / df.resources
df.sort_values("ratio", ascending=False)
```

Which gives you:

```
    resources   score   ratio
7   500         8       0.016000
6   400         6       0.015000
5   400         5       0.012500
0   100         1       0.010000
1   200         2       0.010000
8   1000        9       0.009000
4   400         3       0.007500
3   300         2       0.006667
2   300         1       0.003333
```

Now you can see the best trade-offs at the top and worst ones at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

IIUC, you want to get the max score per resource and the min resource per score simultaneously.

You can compute both and get the intersection:

```
import numpy as np

idx1 = df.groupby('resources')['score'].idxmax().values
# array([0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8])

idx2 = df.groupby('score')['resources'].idxmin().values
# array([0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

out = df.loc[np.intersect1d(idx1, idx2)]
```

output:

```
   resources  score
0        100      1
1        200      2
6        400      6
7        500      8
8       1000      9
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'resources': [100,200,300,300,400,400,400,500,1000],
                   'score': [1,2,1,2,3,5,6,8,9]})
```

Comment: df7 = pd.DataFrame({'resources': [18133,18399,18649,18999],
                   'score': [400,100,300,200]}) The answer could not solve this example....all points except first row has to be dropped.

Comment: Well I'm sorry but the logic remains elusive. It should be clear. Maybe suggest a pen and paper loop algorithm